# How to authenticate Octokit using Github Oauth access_token

Tags: github-api, octokit-js, github-oauth

I'm building a GitHub Oauth app, and I'm trying to authenticate Octokit using an Oauth `access_token` that I'm getting when the user clicks `sign in with Github`.

The `access_token` I'm using has access to the `repo` scope, but when I try to authenticate Octokit with this token, I get: `HttpError: A JSON web token could not be decoded`

Here is my code:

```js
let TOKEN = "<Token>"

const appOctokit = new Octokit({
    auth: TOKEN
});
```

I've also tried authenticating like this:

```js
const appOctokit = new Octokit({
        authStrategy: createOAuthAppAuth,
        auth: {
            clientId: "<Client_ID>",
            clientSecret: "<Client_Secret>",
        },
});
```

but when I do that, and I try deleting an issue using octokit, I get an `HttpError: Not Found` error.

Comment: did you find a solution ? I think I'm trying to do the same thing